# What does "User was removed" mean?

Tags: support, user-accounts

In my activity summary on programmers I have an entry

```
- 5 User was removed
```

What does this mean? Which user was removed and how is my user account related to this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the user was ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, for the reasons he posted here: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/4034/1130. I know he was asking for his account to be deleted, and when I came in this morning I had lost rep too and his user no longer existed

Comment: I find it is a pity that ThorbjørnRavnAndersen has left. Honestly, I have some reasons of criticism towards the site as well. Especially, I do not like flame wars that arise (and questions that get closed) any time certain programming languages are even mildly criticized (not all programming languages, only some). Or that answers often get voted because they support a commonly accepted view and not because they are deep or well explained. So, I had considered leaving a number of times, still resisting for now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A user who had voted on one of your posts had their account deleted, either by choice or because they violated the [Terms of Service](http://stackexchange.com/legal). When that happens, the user's votes go away as well. -5 means that you had earned +5 points from them, probably via a question upvote, and unfortunately that reputation no longer exists.

As for which account was removed, that's not something we should share in public, sorry.

Comment: Thanks. I was not interested to know who the removed user was. Knowing the relation of his / her account to mine (question up-vote) is enough.

Comment: @Giorgio It could be any combination of votes that would produce a +5 total, question upvote is just the simpler solution to the equation.

Comment: This is a problem across all SE websites; see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130122/more-descriptive-user-was-removed-explanation